# Nodejs "child_process" spawn variable undefined

Tags: node.js

my function:

```
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const prc = spawn("free", []);

    function run(cmd, callback) {

            var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
            var command = spawn(cmd)
            var result = ''
            command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                result += data.toString()
            });
            command.on('close', function(code) {
                callback(result)
            });
            command.on('error', function(err) { reject(err) })

    }

    var t;
    run('ls', function (result) {
        t=result; 
        console.log(t); // It works
    });

    console.log(t); //undefined
```

console.log(t) It works and print correctly.

while the console.log(t) out of the function return undefined.

But to solve the problem,
do I need to use Promise or await/async?

Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to execute it before the result is assigning(it's running asynchronously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to asynchronous programming. `console.log(t);` will actually run before `run('ls', function (result) {
        t=result; 
        console.log(t); // It works
});`

Promises are used in conjunction with async/await:

```
(async function() {
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const prc = spawn("free", []);

function run(cmd) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var command = spawn(cmd)
        var result = ''
        command.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            result += data.toString()
        });
        command.on('close', function(code) {
            t = result
            resolve(result)
        });
        command.on('error', function(err) { reject(err) })
        }   
}

var t;
await run('ls');

console.log(t); //defined!
})()
```